# Finding sum of every combination of elements from multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have n integer arrays. I want to iterate over every combination of elements from each array. For example, if:

```
A = [1, 4, 5]
B = [3, 7, 9]
C = [2, 0, -6]
```

A possible combination would be `[1, 7, 0]`.

Each iteration, I want to check if the sum of the combination is equal to a certain number.

I tried to do that by first generating the cartesian product and then iterating over every single combination. The probkem is that even if I had only 7 array with 10 elements each, the cartesian product's length 10,000,000, and so it's not very efficient.

Is there a known algorithm for this problem? Something like sliding window, but for this case?

Comment: Why not just go through each array in nested loops, each with a different index? Can you have too many arrays to do that manually? Do you have an array of arrays? If so please specify more details.

Comment: I have an array of n arrays, and I don't knkw what n is and what length each one of the arrays is

Comment: Did I misunderstand your problem? Is generating the whole cartesian product the inefficient part, or is it the iteration over all combinations? If the latter, then I remove my answer.

Comment: @Nelfeal Iterating over 10 million things will not be efficient.

Comment: @btilly 10 million is not that big. I get around 100ms total in C++ on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/1xofjn4f8) (with optimizations of course). Granted if you up the number of arrays and elements in each, it quickly becomes slow, but that seems to be the nature of the problem. If OP is generating the cartesian product beforehand, I can see it being way slower.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/154695/755

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an array of `n` arrays, you can create an array of `n` indices and take each possible index value one by one.

In C++, it would look like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> inputs; // n input arrays
std::vector<std::size_t> indices(inputs.size(), 0); // n indices, initialized to 0

bool looped_over_all_combinations = false;
while (!looped_over_all_combinations) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (auto i = 0u; i < inputs.size(); ++i) {
        sum += inputs[i][indices[i]];
    }
    if (sum == target_number) {
        // do something
    }

    // next combination
    auto i = indices.size() - 1;
    while (indices[i] == inputs[i].size() - 1) {
        indices[i] = 0;
        if (i == 0) {
            looped_over_all_combinations = true;
            break;
        }
        --i;
    }
    ++indices[i];
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5984Mdefe)

The summing part and the next combination part should both be functions, but hopefully this gives you the idea.

Comment: This is the cartesian product approach. As was already pointed out in the problem, its performance is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a variation of the knapsack problem so this is also an NP complete problem, but I implemented a faster DP based solution!

```py
def solve(arrays, goal):
    dp = dict()
    for arr_ind, arr in enumerate(arrays):
        temp_dp = dict()
        for v in arr:
            for k in list(dp.keys()):
                if not arr_ind or len(dp[k]) == arr_ind:
                    temp_dp[v + k] = dp[k] + (v,)
            if not arr_ind:
                temp_dp[v] = (v,)
        for k, v in temp_dp.items():
            dp[k] = v
            
    if goal in dp:
        return dp[goal]
    return []
```

This solution takes one number from every single array and tries to sum that into to the goal value.